# Lógica para instrução SQL - Soma de valores entre Tabela A e Tabela B

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

A **tabela A** é a tabela que recebe várias linhas contendo diferentes valores relacionados à **tabela B** que é onde se armazena os itens.

**Tabela A**

```
Descrição | Valor
item 1    | 50,00
item 1    | 40,00
item 2    | 10,00
```

**Tabela B**

```
Descrição | Valor
item 1    | 100,00
item 2    | 100,00
```

---

Estou tentando fazer com que a instrução selecione as descrições da **tabela A** cujos valores sejam inferiores à **tabela B**.
O fato de eu estar agrupando é porque há linhas com mesma descrição tratando-se do mesmo item, porém com valores diferentes.

```
SELECT tabela_A.descricao
FROM tabela_A
         INNER JOIN tabela_B
WHERE tabela_A.id = tabela_B.id
  AND (SELECT SUM(tabela_A.valor)
       FROM tabela_A
                INNER JOIN tabela_B
       WHERE tabela_A.id = tabela_B.id
       GROUP BY tabela_B.descricao) < tabela_B.valor
GROUP BY tabela_B.descricao
```

Assim seria mais prático, porém está errado. Mas pode ajudar a entender melhor o ponto que quero chegar:

```
SELECT tabela_A.descricao, SUM(tabela_A.valor) AS _valor
FROM tabela_A
         INNER JOIN tabela_B
WHERE tabela_A.id = tabela_B.id
  AND _valor < tabela_B.valor
GROUP BY tabela_B.descricao
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não seria:

```
SELECT tabela_B.descricao
FROM tabela_B INNER JOIN tabela_A ON (tabela_A.descricao = tabela_B.descricao)
GROUP BY tabela_A.descricao
HAVING SUM(tabela_A.valor) < tabela_B.valor
```

Comment: Exatamente isso!
Como no segundo exemplo, queria acessar a função SOMA para poder dar sequência ao meu código.
Fiz diferentes tentativas para chegar aqui e me deparar com uma cláusula SQL que eu nunca tinha visto, vulgo **HAVING**.
Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que seu **Inner Join** esta errado falou a clausura **ON**, eu não tentei no sqlite mas a  maioria funciona diferente.
Alem de vc esta comparando **tabela_a.id com tabela_a.id** e **tabela_b.id com tabela_b.id**

```
SELECT tabela_A.descricao
FROM tabela_A
         INNER JOIN tabela_B on tabela_b.id = tabela_a.id 
  where(SELECT SUM(tabela_A.valor)
       FROM tabela_A
                INNER JOIN tabela_B on tabela_b.id = tabela_a.id 
       GROUP BY tabela_B.descricao) < tabela_B.valor
GROUP BY tabela_B.descricao
```

Comment: Aaah sim... Me esqueci deste detalhe.
Quanto a comparação da tabela A com tabela A foi falta de atenção ao postar. Eu usei um exemplo fictício pra ficar melhor o entendimento, mas está correto no meu código.
A verdade é que eu estou achando que fazer tudo com SQL não vai dar certo, vou ter que apelar pra condições via PHP.
Agradeço sua ajuda desde já!